# How do I convert a `DateTime` to the corresponding date and time in Berlin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, dst

Given a (UTC) `DateTime` object, how can I get the corresponding time in Berlin, in CET or CEST, depending on the date?

Examples for the desired "convert" function:

```
convert(DateTime.new(2018, 07))
=> Sun, 01 Jul 2018 02:00:00 +0200
convert(DateTime.new(2018, 12))
=> Sat, 01 Dec 2018 01:00:00 +0100
```

Comment: Can you please add some example what exactly you want ?

Comment: Do you mean from UTC to Berlin or from a given local timezone to Berlin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
require 'tzinfo'

timezone = TZInfo::Timezone.get('Europe/Berlin')
local_time = timezone.utc_to_local(utc_time)
```

That even works without Rails.